# advanced :hover deeper nested

Tags: css, css-selectors

I don't know exactly how I can describe this? I think its better if you look at the jsfiddle I have made..

As you can see there is a hover on some TR elements and if the TD already has another bgcoler it has to change to an alternative bgcolor..

It works fine in the first 3 rows, but if there is nested a new table deeper in the DOM the green TD's in the new table does always have the :hover class

### jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/VvZuV/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
tr:hover td.green, tr.deep:hover td.green {
    background:#7bcf81;
}
```

To this:

```
tr:hover > td.green, tr.deep:hover > td.green {
    background:#7bcf81;
}
```

No new class needed.

http://jsfiddle.net/rCztp/

---

**Explanation**

As soon as you hovered over the `<tr>` that contained the `<table>`, all children, grand-children, and etc, were affected by your css rule. Using `>` means that only children will be affected.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I thought that the grey background on the entire "expanded table" was not supposed to be there on `:hover`.

Comment: He complained about the green nested ones, so I just aimed for those.